# Run shell_exec Function in PHP Not Work

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

run "mumudvb -l"  command in the  linux terminal has correct output.
but in php the output is nothing.like this:

```
$output = exec('mumudvb -l');

$output = shell_exec('mumudvb -l');

 $output = "" //the output
```

why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this function because php.ini know it's disabled functions in config file

+Solution: 
Open your php.ini, find `disable_functions` and remove your function then restart web server. BTW, becareful because security problem you may have. You should improve your server security

Comment: i commented  disable_functions in php.ini but not worked :(

Answer (score 0):

On Linux machines, setting that certain value in php.ini does not always work.

What I did was add the following sudoers group: `%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` then make the www-data user run as admin `usermod -G admin www-data` next, all the commands that you use with shell_exec, prefix them with sudo.